# How to register facts of remote host using Ansible?

Tags: automation, ansible, ansible-2.x

I want to register facts of the remote host into var and then iterate over the var in next task. but I am stuck on first task of registering facts with hostname [hostname:IP]. Following is my code :

```
- name: get facts
  setup:
  delegate_to: "{{item}}"
  delegate_facts: True
  with_items: "{{ groups['hadoop'] }}"
  register: hadoop_ips
  tags:
    - etc-hosts

- debug: msg={{ hadoop_ips }}
  tags:
    - etc-hosts
```

Comment: What exactly is the error you are getting?

Answer (score 3):

If you want to fetch Ansible facts about a host you should use [`hostvars`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#magic-variables-and-how-to-access-information-about-other-hosts) to access them after having gathered facts on the hosts.

If your playbook will have already gathered facts for the hosts you are interested in or you are using [fact caching](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#fact-caching) and the cache holds the facts about the hosts then you can just use `hostvars` directly. If not then you will need to use a delegated [`setup`](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/setup_module.html) task like you have in your question.

So if you want to fetch the default IP addresses for some hosts in another group not targeted by your current playbook you might have something like this:

```
- name: get facts
  setup:
  delegate_to: "{{item}}"
  delegate_facts: True
  with_items: "{{ groups['hadoop'] }}"
  tags:
    - etc-hosts

- debug: var={{ hostvars[item]['ansible_eth0']['ipv4']['address'] }}
  with_items: "{{ groups['hadoop'] }}"
  tags:
    - etc-hosts
```

Comment: I tried the changes recommended by you but got this error FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "'dict object' has no attribute 'ansible_eth0'"}. I do see ansible_eth0 in ansible setup https://gist.github.com/anonymous/ce3fdc54650c8e91c5a0